# Facebook post to promotion wall dialog

Tags: facebook

I have a promotional Facebook page set up which anyone is allowed to comment on.

Is it possible to create a dialog that prompts Facebook users (who have not added an application of mine or anything like that) to post to this wall, in the same way as you can create a "post link to users own wall" dialog without any permissions (basically the "share this page" dialog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this.  Via the FB.ui method. The important part is the `to` parameter of the FB.ui

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        to: facebookPageId, // sends to the post to the page 
        link: urlToShare,
        picture: imageForLink,
        caption: captionForLink,
        name: nameOf,
        description: descriptionForLink
}, 
    function(response) {
        if(response && response.post_id) alert('Posted!');
        return true;
});
```